# StopIteration error when creating a dataframe from a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dictionary

So I have created a dataframe from a dictionary to perform a time series exercise. When I create the dataframe (I'm doing this in Google Colab) the cell runs correctly. but when I do `full_df.head()`. I get `StopIteration` error. Does anyone know why this happens?

This is what I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv', usecols=["close", "Name"])

gp = df.groupby("Name")
my_dict = {} 
for record in gp: 
    if record[0] in my_dict:
       my_dict[record[0]].append(record)
    else:
       my_dict[record[0]] = [record]

full_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')

full_df.head() #This is where I get the error.
```

[image: This is a part of the dictionary]

Comment: Provide test data.

Comment: I have added a part of the dictionary @hpchavaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to assign tuples as single column.

The looping over the result of `.groupby` results in a pair `(key, sub_df)` where the `key` is this group name. The `sub_df` is a DataFrame with all columns and with all values associated with given `key`. Your loop creates a one element list (where element is the mentioned tuple) for each `key` in dictionary.

This dictionary would represent a DataFrame with only one column (because each entry in the dictionary is a one-element list) with each row containing tuple of string and dataframe. Pandas has no idea how to translate that into the proper DataFrame.

If I understand the intention correctly, then you want to have names in the index and close values in each row. For that it is better to use [pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) function. I found your [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/all_stocks_5yr.csv) to try solving it. I recommend loading the `date` column. You can pivot the loaded DataFrame with:

```
final_df = df.pivot(columns="date", index="Name", values="close")
final_df.head()
```

Result:
[image: result1]

If you don't have access to the `date` column, you can assign increasing values of index in each group with [cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html?highlight=cumcount#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount). Using following code:

```
df['date'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
final_df = df.pivot(columns="date", index="Name", values="close")
final_df.head()
```

You get this:
[image: result2]

#### Edit:

If you want to use dictionary, then you need to be careful what you put as a value. As the `df.groupby('Name')` returns iterable of tuples, then we can unpack it as `key, group`. The `group` is also a DataFrame, so we need to select the column (in this case 'close'). We need to covert selected column to Numpy array (or reset index), otherwise the `group` index would be used by Pandas as column names in the new DataFrame. Code example:

```
my_dict = {key: group['close'].to_numpy() for key, group in df.groupby('Name')}
full_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
full_df.head()
```

which return:
[image: result2]

Comment: and how do I add the dictionary I created? or is it better to remove the dictionary and do it with pivot?

Comment: It is better to do with pivot, instead of the dictionary (free performance and clean code). But if you want to use the dictionary, I'll provide the code example in the answer edit.

Comment: yes, could you provide the answer using the dictionary too? if it is not much trouble

Comment: I've added the dictionary example. Is it clear?

Comment: yes, thank you so much!

Comment: I there a way to add the dates instead of the increasing numbers when doing it with the dictionary?

Comment: Yes. If you have `date` column you can assign it as an index in each group, instead of using Numpy array. The index of resulting pandas Series in each group will become the column names: `my_dict = 
 {key: group.set_index('date')['close'] for key, group in df.groupby('Name')}`